# *ngFor not showing any data

Tags: asp.net, angular

I'm creating a chatting app.  I have a slight problem, `ngFor` doesnt seem to work for me.

I have 2 components, 1 is the feed which holds the other component which is the message. So feed shows a list of message components.

Feed
.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Message } from '../models/message';
import { MessageService } from '../core/message.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-feed',
  templateUrl: './feed.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./feed.component.css']
})
export class FeedComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  feed: Observable<Message[]>;

  constructor(private msgService: MessageService) { }

  getMessages(): Observable<Message[]> {
    return this.msgService.getAllMessages();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.feed = this.getMessages();
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.feed = this.getMessages();
  }
}
```

Feed .html

```
<div class="feed">
  <div *ngIf="feed | async; then fetched else fetching">
  </div>

  <ng-template #fetched>
    <div *ngFor="let message of feed$ | async" class="message">
      <app-message [message]=message></app-message>
    </div>
  </ng-template>

  <ng-template #fetching>
    <h3>Loading...</h3>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

Message .ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { Message } from '../models/message';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-message',
  templateUrl: './message.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./message.component.css']
})
export class MessageComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() message: Message;
  sender: string;
  body: string;
  createdAt: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(message = this.message) {
    this.sender = message.Sender;
    this.body = message.Body;
    this.createdAt = message.CreatedAt;
  }
}
```

Message .html

```
<div class="messageContainer">
  <div class="messageData">
    <span class="sender">
      <p>{{sender}}</p>
    </span>
    <span class="createdAt">
      <p>{{createdAt | date:'medium'}}</p>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="messageContent">
    {{body}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Also here is my service which does an API call from my asp.net project.

MessageService .ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Message } from '../models/message';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MessageService {

  private readonly baseUrl = 'http://localhost:50169';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAllMessages(): Observable<Message[]> {
    return this.http.get<Message[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/api/messages`);
  }
}
```

I've tried checking the value of the API call and it has value based on the console log.

My problem is it does not show any data on the `ngFor` of the feed component.

Comment: try it without `ngOnChanges`

Comment: Just the same without `ngOnChanges`

Comment: Your problem is resolved or not can u please let us know if resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are missing a set of quotes around the attribute value.
2. You are referencing a variable named `feed$` in your template but the field in your component is named `feed`.
3. you are assigning `feed` in `ngInit`, this means that it will also evaluate to `true` if you do a truthy check on it. As such there is no need to check it's value as it will always evaluate to `true` once your template renders.

Fixed `feed.component.html` template:

```
<div class="feed">
  <div *ngFor="let message of feed | async" class="message">
    <app-message [message]="message"></app-message>
  </div>
</div>
```